# Scroll until an element is located by link text in selenium

Tags: c#, facebook, selenium, scroll

I was working with selenium web driver and was trying to find an element on Facebook page but my element is hidden under loading more stories in their growing feed. I would like to scroll until I find that element.

I have tried two things which are:

```
IWebElement bio = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("link"));
```

((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    Thread.Sleep(500);

and

```
IWebElement bio = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("link"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(bio);
actions.Perform();
```

both of them show me an error.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solution is scroll the page until you find the element.

**Try with this.**

```
int y_axis = 250;
while(driver.findElements(By.linkText("link")).size()<1){
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+y_axis+")", "");
    y_axis = y_axis+250;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in C# i am able to do only .Size.Height or .Size.Width and that is also giving me an error

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you trying to do on Facebook?

Comment: @Monika - I am trying to automate a group managing to delete advertised links on that page. I just need to do scroll. Rest of my page is working properly.

Comment: @Vishesh-gupta : can you please give the error details as well.

Comment: @Monika - My code picks up the first element with the linktext, link, and deletes it so I wanted to scroll to every element with the linktext(link) in it and then delete it but in this i get an error of element not found. I also think that since it is a growing scroll page, the elements are hidden so I cannot find them. Kindly help